# SQL, adding specific transactions for a particular drink on the same order

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working on seeing which coffee drink sells the most extra condiments (or accessory items like expresso shots, syrup, etc.). Everything is in our MSTransaction, MSOrderLine, or MSProduct tables.

[image]

This is the MSorderline table, the extra condiments are ProductID 1444 and 1445. For example, for Purchase ID 421 there was 4 condiments bought for ProductID 1493. So at this point down the list Product 1493 would have 4 sold.

I've been messing around with this and I can't get the results I want...

[image]

I understand that this solution wouldn't be correct, but this is as close as I know how to get.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I think what you want is to sum quantity for a purchaseID that has productID of 1444 or 1445 and there is at least one other productID for the same purchase ID.  Correct?  What result do you want if there are two (or more) productID other than 1444 or 1445? Or, is that not a possible case?

Comment: Nothing. We can't determine what they bought the additives 1444 or 1445 for so anything bought on the purchaseID that includes the two (1445 or 1444) will have a added number to the "TotalCondimentsSold" column.